# ReactJS todo list app remove function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

This is very simple todo list app and this is my practice codes as you see we have a List component to show items ;New item will be added when user input new data by submit function.

This time I'm trying to delete item when span in li is clicked, I think I'm doing wrong.

How can we attach that event to list?

this my App.js:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import './App.css';
import List from "./components/List"

class App extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            term: '',
            items: [],
            remove: function () {
            }
        }
    }

    onChange = (e) => {
        this.setState({term: e.target.value})
    };

    onSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        this.setState({
            items: [...this.state.items, this.state.term]
        })
    };

    removeItem = (item)=>{
        this.setState({
            items: this.state.items.splice(this.state.items.indexOf(item),1)
        })

    };
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="App">
                <form className="App" onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
                    <input value={this.state.term}  onChange={this.onChange}/>
                    <button>submit</button>
                </form>
            <List items={this.state.items}  />
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default App;
```

my List.js component:

```
import React from "react"
import App from "../App";

const listyle = {
    color: 'red'
};

const red = {
    backgroundColor : 'red'
};

const List = (props) => {
    var val = props.items.map(function (data, index) {
        return <li style={listyle} key={index}>{data}<span style={red} onClick={props.remove(data)}>X</span></li>
    });
    return <ul>{val}</ul>
};

export default List;
```

Comment: You aren’t passing your remove function to your List component?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to pass the `removeItem` function to the `List` component and pass a function to the item `onCLick` as well.

*App.js*

```
<List items={this.state.items} onRemove={this.removeItem} />
```

*List.js*

```
// ...
const List = (props) => {

    var val = props.items.map(function (data, index) {
        return <li style={listyle} key={index}>{data}<span style={red} onClick={() => props.onRemove(data)}>X</span></li>
    });

    return <ul>{val}</ul>
};
// ...
```

Comment: why when i try to remove one item,  all item will delete except first item?

Comment: The proplem is that `this.state.items.splice` mutates the original array and returns the item that removed. Use `this.state.items.filter(i => i !== item)` will work as expected. Demo: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/XPradp?editors=0010

Comment: Yes .. Thankyou